# merge two preg_replace statments to one

Tags: php, preg-replace

I try to combine two preg_replace statements to one.

first statement:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\/\\*\\*\//","",$string); // to remove any "/**/" frome the string.
```

second statement:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\/\//","",$string); // to remove any "//" from the string.
```

my goals are:

1. remove all occurrence of `/\**/` without any chars between them.

   e.g. `/\*//\*/` should not be removed.
2. remove all `//` that are not part of a `/\*\*/`.

   e.g. `//**/` should left the first `/` because of step 1. but in case of `/\*//\*/` the `//` between the two `*` should not be removed.
3. get step 1 and 2 in one `preg_replace` statement.

   the leftover in the string should be any `*` or `/` that not match the conditions in step1 or step2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an alternation:

```
$string = "Hello//World!/**/";
echo $string . "\n";
$string = preg_replace("/\/\\*\\*\/|\/\//", "", $string);
echo $string;
```

This prints:

```
Hello//World!/**/
HelloWorld!
```

Comment: thank you very much! it seems to work just fine! the only thing i found is that if the string is "/*//*/" the "//" gets removed... but since the outter part "/**/" is still in the string the validation still finds not a empty string whats good enough for me.